# Why is the ListBox returning nil or no Object right after adding an object into the list?

Tags: object, listbox, nullreferenceexception, delphi-prism

Here is the system.object:

```
  TTrendGroup = class(System.Object)
    SigList:ArrayList;
    Rate,Phase,Delay:SmallInt;
    RateIndex,PhaseIndex:SmallInt;
    firstTime:Boolean;
    base:integer;
    Enabled:Boolean;
    name:string;
    public
    constructor;
    method AddTGroup(signal:TTrendSignal);
    method Clear;
    method Poll(list:ArrayList);
    method ReadTGroup(bTGr:BinaryReader);
    method WriteTGroup(bTGw:BinaryWriter);
    method WriteSignals(bWSw:BinaryWriter);
    method ToString:String;override;
  end;

constructor TTrendGroup;
begin
  SigList := new ArrayList;
  Rate := 30;
  Phase := 0;
  Delay := Phase;
  RateIndex := 4;
  PhaseIndex := 0;
  firsttime := true;
  enabled := true;
  name := '';
end;
```

Here is how I create an object from the above system.object and add it to my GroupList ListBox:

```
method HTrendFrm.AddGroup1_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var
  i:integer;
  grp:TTrendGroup;
begin
  if ReadWrite then
  begin
    grp := new TTrendGroup;
    grp.name:='New Group';
    i := GroupList.Items.Add(grp);
    GroupList.SelectedIndex := i;
    grpName.Text := 'New Group';
    PollBtn.Checked := grp.Enabled;
    RateBox.SelectedIndex := grp.RateIndex;
    PhaseBox.SelectedIndex:= grp.PhaseIndex;
    SignalListBox.Items.Clear;
    UpdateButtons;
  end;
end;
```

Here is how I try to retrieve the system.object I just added back out:

```
method HTrendFrm.GroupList_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
 var
  grp:TTrendGroup;
begin
  if (GroupList.SelectedIndex = -1) then exit;
  with GroupList do
  begin
    grp := TTrendGroup(items[SelectedIndex]); <<<<< HERE is WHERE THE PROBLEM IS. grp always returns NIL.
  end;
end;
```

I don't know why. I have very similar code in other part of this program and they work as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if (GroupList.Items.Count<=0) and (GroupList.SelectedIndex = -1) then exit;   should be  if (GroupList.Items.Count=0) or (GroupList.SelectedIndex = -1) then exit;  or possibly just  if GroupList.SelectedIndex = -1 then exit;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , Okay I made the changes to the code...Well the way my program is running strangely I overlooked that little logic error.

Answer (score 1):

When the returned object is `nil`, did you verify the `SelectedIndex` value is actually valid?  Your code has a logic bug in it that allows `SelectedIndex` to be `-1` when the ListBox is not empty.  Your `if` statement needs to use the `or` operator instead of the `and` operator:

```
// if (GroupList.Items.Count<=0) and (GroupList.SelectedIndex = -1) then exit;
if (GroupList.Items.Count<=0) or (GroupList.SelectedIndex = -1) then exit;
```

Comment: How can `GroupList.Items.Count` ever be `< 0`. The `<=` is not needed; a simple `GroupList.Items.Count = 0` would suffice. :)

Comment: @KenWhite, You are absolutely correct. I overlooked this simple bug for I was more concentrating on why I can't seem to retrieve the system.object out of ListBox without getting nil error message. Yes, I did verify that returned object grp is set to NIL.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I have made the changes to the code and verified the selectedIndex value is correct. Still, it is returning Nil. I am confused.